# pyttsx3 in Django

Tags: python, django

This code works on python shell but doesn't work on localhost
The main purpose of code is, to make application say 'hi' every second

in python

```
from time import sleep
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()


def say(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def runAfter(function):
    def wrapper():
        while True:
            function()
            sleep(1)
    return wrapper


@runAfter
def sayHi():
    arg = 'hi'
    print(f'say({arg})')
    say(arg)

sayHi()
```

in django

```
@runAfter
def sayHi():
    arg = 'hi'
    print(f'say({arg})')
    say(arg)


def test(responce):
    sayHi()
    return HttpResponse('<h1>test</h1>')
```

in django it says 'hi' once